# What is the difference between playing Animator State and/or playing AnimationClip ? And why i can't play animation clips?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The states and animations not my own.

I have a prefab of a character that have Animator component attached to it. The character in the Hierarchy have Animator with some states and blends and also have some animation clips.

Now when i play/run a State of the Animator is that meaning i'm playing animation? Or the animation clips is something else ?

And why i can't playing the animation clips ? I'm not getting errors or exceptions it's just not playing it.

Here is a script that attached to this character and i also added to this character a Animation component. So now the character object have both Animator and Animation components.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    private int index = 0;
    private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController controller;
    private UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorState[] an;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        an = GetStateNames(animator);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            animator.Play(an[index].name);
            if (++index == an.Length)
                index = 0;
        }
    }

    private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorState[] GetStateNames(Animator animator)
    {
        controller = animator ? animator.runtimeAnimatorController as UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController : null;
        return controller == null ? null : controller.layers.SelectMany(l => l.stateMachine.states).Select(s => s.state).ToArray();
    }

    private void RollSound()
    {

    }

    private void CantRotate()
    {

    }

    private void EndRoll()
    {

    }

    private void EndPickup()
    {

    }
}
```

Inside the variable an there are 9 states:

```
Aiming
Death_A
Use
Grounded
Roll
PickupObject
Reload_Rifle
Shoot_Rifle
Empty
```

When i click on A key it's playing the states one by one each time i click on A Everything is working fine i can play the 9 states by clicking on A.

what i don't understand with the States is inside the editor when i'm in the hierarchy selecting the character and in the menu make: Window > Animator i see the 9 states on the LegsLayer:

[image: 9 States]

But then if i click on state Grounded double click i see a blend tree and i'm not sure if this is also states or maybe this is animation clips ? Then how can i get access to them ?

[image: Blend Tree]

Ok this is one part i don't understand yet about the Animator and what and how i can play with it.

The second part is related to AnimationClip/s and why i can't play them ?

The script for animations clips:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Animations;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animation animation; 
    private AnimationClip[] animationClips; 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
        animationClips = AnimationUtility.GetAnimationClips(gameObject);

        foreach (AnimationClip clip in animationClips)
        {
            animation.AddClip(clip, clip.name);
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            animation.clip = animationClips[6];
            animation.Play(animationClips[6].name);
        }
    }

    private void RollSound()
    {

    }

    private void CantRotate()
    {

    }

    private void EndRoll()
    {

    }

    private void EndPickup()
    {

    }

    private void FootStep()
    {

    }
}
```

And in the variable animationClips i have 9 animations:

```
Rifle_Aiming_Idle
Rifle_Aiming_Walk_F_RM
Rifle_Aiming_Walk_B_RM
Rifle_Aiming_Walk_L_RM
Rifle_Aiming_Walk_R_RM
Rifle_Idle
Rifle_Walk_F_RM
Rifle_Run_F_RM
Rifle_Sprint_F_RM
```

When i'm running the game and clicking on A this time i see in the Inspector inside the Animation component all the animation clips and in Animation i see the animation clip to play.

I'm not getting any errors or exceptions but it's just not playing it. The character stay still idle. Even if i choose another animation clip index to play 5 or 3 or 1 nothing is playing.

I wonder why it's not playing the animations when i click A. In this case animation number 6 from the List but still not playing.

[image: Animations in inspector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Animation component is a legacy component, kept in Unity to ensure backward compatibility with older projects, so you should never use it for animations.

Basically, the system works this way:

- First of all, you need an `Animator Controller` asset. This Animator is a Finite State Machine (with substates etc.), and every single state can have an `Animation Clip` (you assign it via script of via Inspector in the `Motion` field). When the FSM enters a specific state, it will play the `Animation Clip` assigned.
  Clearly the `Animator`, in order to be used by a game object, has to be assigned to that object via the `Animator` component.
- `Animation Clips` are assets which contain the actual animation, they're never assigned as components to game objects, but instead they must be referenced by an `Animator` to be played, as I said before.
- Blend trees are used to blend different animations in a seamless way by using linear interpolation. They're a "special" state of the Animator, which has multiple Animation Clips that you can interpolate to display transitions from a state to another, for example when you need to change the animation among running forward, running left and running right.

The argument is very broad, you can start to get into it by reading the official documentation about Animators, Animation Clips and Blend Trees here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationSection.html

Comment: I'm going to read it. But just to see if i understood it in general: If i want to play one of this animation clips i need to create a new state in the animator and then add a animation clip to this state and then when i will play the state it will play the animation.  ( Just like i'm playing the states now and it's working but i need to add the animation clip/s to a state so i can play it ).

Comment: Yes, that's it. The `Animator Controller` contains States which (may) contain an `Animation Clip` (or more, if the State is a Blend Tree).